# How to ping a server from an android tablet

Tags: android, ping, inetaddress

I am trying to write an android tablet application which scans for a set of ip addresses in the local network and check whether they are in use or alive. I am using the

```
InetAddress.getByName(ipAd).isReachable(100)
```

but when i check the logs it returns false and true on certain computers on the network. I tried pinging the machines manually and it works like a charm but from the android device not all computers return true. I had also allowed ICMP ping requests on the firewalls of the machines in the local network.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks in Advance

Cheers

Comment: Did you try to increase the timeout value? Even though it should be enough for local ping you might get higher values depending on network load, device load etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it out. what i did was  I sent a broadcast message and implemented a UDPListener. which replied to my broadcast message.

thanks for hte help in advance

Cheers